# ChartJs - chartjs-plugin-datalabels How to make datalabels outside of the line

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

i create radar chart using `chartJ`s and use `chartJs-plugin-datalabels` for my charts.

until now, i create the chart like this
[image: myRadarChart]

but i need to draw the labels like this

[image: expectationChart]

so far i do this to my option in chart, i set the anchor to 'end' but its doesnt work.

```
 options: {
           plugins: {
             datalabels: {
                color: 'white',
                backgroundColor: function(context){
                      if(context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex] <= 20){
                                    return 'red'
                      } else if (context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex] <= 30){
                                    return 'orange'
                      } else if (context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex] <= 40){
                                    return 'purple'
                      }
                        else if (context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex] <= 40){
                                    return 'lightblue'
                      } else {
                                    return 'green'
                      }
                },
                borderRadius: 5,
                padding : 5,
                anchor: 'end',
           }
       },
  }
```

Comment: "Like this" what is the main difference?... No API for this idea (If you talk about long lines outside of the shape).

Comment: i mean the position of the labels